# Build Agent - TFS 2008

Tags: msbuild, build-agent

I have been told that a build agent can only build projects of certain types on a given port e.g. build1 on port 9191 can build .net framework 2.0 and for .net framework 4.0, there has to a different build agent configured and then so on? is that right? i couldn't find much on google. if you have any relevant information, could you please pass me the link?

Answer (score 0):

Nop. This is not true. There is no relation between build agent port number and .Net framework version in TFS2008.

Comment: are you able to forward me any documentation or article that explains it further please?